# Rename metadata property in bulk

Tags: powershell, managed-metadata, term-store

I have a document library with documents that are tagged with Metadata from the term store.  I want to delete the term and rename all the documents with the tag 1.3 for example to 1.0.  Deleting the term is easy is there a powershell script to rename the metadata tags?